# Node.js node canvas show base64 image

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, canvas, node-canvas

I'm currently transfering a `base64` image from a client to my server with `socket.io`. On the server, I want to render that `base64` image into my canvas.

The code is:

```
function newSlide(slideImage){
  socket.broadcast.emit('newSlide', slideImage);
  var img = new Image;
  img.src = slideImage;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

With that code, on the client everything is working, I can load the base64 image into a normal canvas, but on my server in `server.js` (where this code is), it's not working, I'm getting an error saying `Image is not defined` at the line `new Image`, when trying without the image-creation and just put in the `base64` string, it says image or canvas excepted.

What's the problem with the image creation, why does it not work? And what can I do to make it working?

Comment: You can't display the image on the server, you need to display it on the client side.. you probably want to just send the image data over to the client, have the client receive and display it.

Comment: @LiamMacDonald but I somehow need it on the server side... after it is in node-canvas it goes on, so I need it there

Answer (score 2):

[`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) is part of the DOM API and so is not present in the Node runtime.

To do what you want you're going to have to import a module that allows you to emulate some of the DOM APIs.

Comment: I've never needed to use one myself but [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) might be able to help

Comment: looks not that easy...I'm wondering if there is a way to maybe create a canvas with directly that base64 without converting it to an image?

Answer (score 0):

[`node-canvas`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) provides `loadImage` which accepts base64 and appears to be a promisified `Image()` at a quick glance (although it provides `Image` as well, which seems to work fine just like the browser):

```js
const {createCanvas, loadImage} = require("canvas"); // ^2.11.0
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");

(async () => {
  // sample (very small) base64 image
  const b64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII";
  const img = await loadImage(b64);
  const canvas = createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
  canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // just to show it worked, convert back to base64 and write to file
  await fs.writeFile("test.png", canvas.toDataURL().split(",")[1], "base64");
})();
```